# Dynamically creating an angular view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm making an in game UI using awesomium, at some points the game loads up and executes a chunk of javascript which is meant to create arbitrary new UI elements. e.g.

```
jQuery(document.body).append('<span class="game-status-alert">You Lose!</span>');
```

That works nicely, the problem comes when I want to create some slightly more advanced UI elements, specifically using angular. For example something like:

```
function ChatBoxControl($scope) { /* Stuff */ }

jQuery(document.body).append(
    '<div ng-controller="ChatBoxControl"><div ng-repeat="line in chat"><span>{{line}}</span></div></div>'
);
```

Not surprisingly, this does not create a new angular view. It simply adds that html to the document and never binds to the ChatBoxControl.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) dynamically added angular content. 
Something like:

```
jQuery(document.body).append(
    $compile(  
        '<div ng-controller="ChatBoxControl"><div ng-repeat="line in chat"><span>{{line}}</span></div></div>'
    )(scope)
);
```

scope for any element you can get using something like:

```
var scope = angular.element('#dynamicContent').scope();
```

Also you should get $compile that can be injected in other controller.

See also: [AngularJS + JQuery : How to get dynamic content working in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771513/angularjs-jquery-how-to-get-dynamic-content-working-in-angularjs)

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, since it uses strings of html and not a reference to a HTML file and is thus closer to my original question :)

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use ng-include combined with ng-repeat.
Here is an simple example: http://plunker.no.de/edit/IxB3wO?live=preview

```
  <div ng-repeat="dom in domList" ng-include="dom"></div>
```

Parent $scope will keep the list of partials loaded into the view.
And ng-repeat + ng-include will iterate over and display partials according
to the list.

When it is the right timing, you can append the partial into the dom list.  e.g.

```
$scope.domList.push("chatbox.html");
```

(BTW, putting DOM manipulation into controller is not the angular way.)

Comment: I understand that DOM manipulation isn't the angular way, but unfortunately it is unavoidable due to the way the game UI system works :(

Comment: By angularjs, it looks like if controller makes DOM manipulations, it's more a "service" then a controller. The service can be then injected into Controller for use. But again, services should have as low amount as possible of DOM manipulations, since then it not testing friendly.