# Adding angular js attribute after page render

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an application that contains a div with content in it. When I click a button jQuery adds a AngularJs directive to the div. After adding the directive i call scope.$apply(), but this doesn't seem to inform angular about the new directive on the div. Can someone explain to me how I can inform AngularJs about the new directive added with jQuery?

Comment: You need to $compile the newly added Angular directive.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12049456/215945

Comment: Yeah... what Mark said. :P I think we have the same browsing habits, this happens once a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be adding directives to your markup with JQuery. Use Angular for that whenever possible.

That said, if you *have* to add directives via straight DOM manipulations like that, you'll need to use the [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) provider to compile the element and bind it to a scope before you add it.