# How do I get a directive to be linked in dynamically loaded HTML in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AngularJS + JQuery : How to get dynamic content working in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771513/angularjs-jquery-how-to-get-dynamic-content-working-in-angularjs)

I have an application based on AngularJS 1.0.1 and Bootstrap 2.0.2.

The application dynamically loads views; I use `angular.bootstrap()` to compile and link these fragments, and AngularJS is appears to be working fine, linking to my model and responding to events.

I want to put a Bootstrap tooltip on some dynamic elements, and have created a directive for this (using the approach laid out by [AlexFigueiredoo](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexFigueiredoo/cRr9K/4/)). This approach works well when the AngularJS view is on static HTML as you can see from the jsFiddle.

However, when the same code is used in an environment where the HTML is dynamically loaded, the popup is not working. Investigating, the 'tooltip' directive is now not being linked.

I have a [test-case](http://jsfiddle.net/aalcock/hFGb7/10/) on jsFiddle. Do bring up your JS console to view the messages.

Note that console.log never shows the directive factory being called, let alone linked.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Raised as issue on AngularJS GitHub: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1335

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added the tooltip attribute to the end of the tag and it worked for me. looks like you forgot the directive on the live example?

http://jsfiddle.net/CcRrN/