# Bootstrap Accordion Suppress Open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this jQuery, which is obviously not working:

```
$('input.descriptionLC').click(function(){
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide')
});
```

My html is being generated by this for loop / append:

```
for (i=0; i < nodeArr.length; i++){
  $('#accordion2').append('<div class="accordion-group">' +
  '<div class="accordion-heading">' +
    '<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse' + i + '">' +  
        '<hr class="inLC">' +
        '<div class="divLC">' +
            '<p class="titleLC">' + nodeArr[i][0] + '</p>' +
            '<p class="imgWrap"><img class="imgLC" src="img/On_slider.png"></p>' +
            '<input type="text" class="descriptionLC" id="description' + i + '">' +
        '</div>' +    
    '</a>' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div id="collapse' + i + '" class="accordion-body collapse">' +
    '<div class="accordion-inner">' +
      'Anim pariatur cliche...' +
    '</div>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>'
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use .on instead of .click as your DOM is changing.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659204/jquery-and-angularjs-bind-events-to-changing-dom). .on will (and should) be used to watch the parent of the changing area for changes; once the changes have been executed it will automatically rebind all of the events to the selected subelements (with the filter). In that answer I give a more detailed description of how to use it.

In short, though this is inefficient (you should change body to some div containing just the changing part of the DOM):

```
$('body').on("click", 'input.descriptionLC', function(e){
      $('.collapse').collapse('hide')
});
```

**if you want just the following accordion item**:

```
$('body').on("click", 'input.descriptionLC', function(e){
      $(this).next('.collapse').collapse('hide')
});
```

Comment: I don't know why, but for some reason, this opens all the accordions on the page, 30+.

Comment: Yes, this will open all of the documents, as you're selecting .collapse for the entire page. If you want just the next one... editing answer

Comment: ?? I want to make none of them open.

Comment: Your question contains code that is obviously meant to open when clicking the thing. If you want to UNBIND that, you can use `$('input.descriptionLC').unbind()`

Comment: Someone edited my title, but the whole point was to make none of them open when the input is active.

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery**

```
$('body').on('click', 'input.descriptionLC', function(e){
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

See [jQuery on docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Really ? I thought it was replacing the live event like that ?

Comment: No, they replaced all of those old events using .on

Comment: so I should better bind the 'body' instead of the document ? Thanks for that !

Comment: Actually you linked to the jquery docs for on anyway, you shouldn't bind to document, rather body or even better the closest containing div to the changing DOM.

Comment: For example if the changing div was surrounded by .container, you should use $('.container'). ...

Comment: ok, but does it bind the events on something that is added with Javascript to the container ?

Comment: No, not at all. jQuery will simply look for clicks within that area. Much more efficient than clicks on the entire page (and actually anywhere in the window)

Comment: Thanks for those informations, I was able to illustrate it [there](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/N3hEq/).