# ng-click does not work with Kendo grid cell template

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I'm trying to use the kendo ui grid and display a link column in an AngularJS application. The column is rendered using a template. I'm using the AngularJS ng-click directive in the template to call a method when the link in a cell is clicked. ng-click does not appear to work in a column template. 
[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fc2dBo6SDJ6WFvemsg1U) is an example.

However a [similar](http://plnkr.co/edit/VDrv8RQGT4tnKdoubBfh) example that DOES NOT use a column template seems to work fine with ng-click.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-click doens't work on dynamic DOM AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296264/ng-click-doenst-work-on-dynamic-dom-angularjs)

Comment: Thanks! $compile did the trick. I added the following line to the end of script.js: $compile($('#productGrid'))($scope);