# ng-click not working on newly appended elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Why is my ng-click not working when I appended it with a button? The same ng-click is working when I initially loaded the button.

```
app.controller('demoCtrl', function() {


          this.clk = '<button ng-click="dctrl.click()">Button</button>';

          this.click = function() {

            alert('clicked');

          }
})

 app.directive('btnClick', function() {

          return {

            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {

              actionBtn: '='

            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

              element.append(scope.actionBtn);

            }

          }

})
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="demoCtrl as dctrl">

        <div btn-click action-btn="dctrl.clk"></div>

</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QPKXfGd9s7HzLvEfKvbG?p=preview

**Update**

I've also tried this way but no luck

```
element.append($compile(scope.actionBtn)(scope));
```

Comment: This might be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296264/ng-click-doenst-work-on-dynamic-dom-angularjs

Comment: @mukesh: I've tried this element.append($compile(scope.actionBtn)(scope)); but not working

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/cbGDbFSXcJQ56rdK7gDN?p=preview

Comment: `element.append($compile(scope.actionBtn)(scope));` won't work because of the isolated scope of the directive

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bkzrvfLm/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Why don't you post your reply as an answer? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You need to [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) an new dom element created manually for angularjs to work on it so

```
app.directive('btnClick', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.append($compile(scope.$eval(attrs.actionBtn))(scope));
        }
    }
}])
```

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('demoCtrl', function() {
  this.clk = '<button ng-click="dctrl.click()">Button</button>';

  this.click = function() {
    alert('clicked');
  }
})

app.directive('btnClick', ['$compile',
  function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.append($compile(scope.$eval(attrs.actionBtn))(scope));
      }
    }
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="demoCtrl as dctrl">
  <div action-btn="dctrl.clk" btn-click></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also the scope mustn't be isolated.

Comment: @JoaoLeal: How can I use this with a isololated scope defined? I have another click function which is happening thorough isolated scope

Comment: @JoaoLeal:  Thank you for the reply. Could you please explain me what does this part do '&onClick'

Comment: This question (and answers) should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908133/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-and-in-angularjs