# AngularJS directive not rendered after DOM change

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have custom directive in HTML partial that is updated in ajax callback.

Initially the directive is rendered and working, but after content update, directive is not rendered anymore.
Any possibility to rebind the directive?

Simple illustration:

HTML:
When page is first loaded, my-directive works.

```
<div class="page">    

 <div class="right-menu">
   <ul>
    <li>
      <my-directive some-attr="1"></my-directive>
    </li>
    <li>
      <my-directive some-attr="1"></my-directive>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

angular script:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', ["service", function (service) {
    return {
      //
    }
};
```

jQuery script:

```
$.get('dynamic-content.php', function (content) {
  $('.right-menu').html(content); // after this, my-directive is not working anymore
});
```

dynamic-content.php:

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <my-directive some-attr="1"></my-directive>
 </li>
 <li>
   <my-directive some-attr="1"></my-directive>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle to illustrate the issue ?

Comment: I provided simple illustration in my question. Hope it helps.

Comment: No, there is not enough information.

Comment: What more do you need? The problem should be simple. Why doesn't Angular render directive when markup for that directive is dynamically loaded/updated in DOM.

Comment: I found solution to my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771513/angularjs-jquery-how-to-get-dynamic-content-working-in-angularjs#answer-24058760 .