# angularjs ng-click for runtime tags not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-click event is working for design time html control but not for runtime control. may be due ng-click event is out of scope in this case.

HTML Code

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
<label class="checkbox">
                <button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime" />Open only one at a time</label>
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">{{group.content}}</accordion-group>
</accordion>
 <button class="btn btn-small" onclick="f()" >Click</button>
<div id=name>
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
 function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {

$scope.oneAtATime = true;

$scope.groups = [{
    title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
    content: "Dynamic Group Body - 1"
}, {
    title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
    content: "Dynamic Group Body - 2"
}];

$scope.addItem = function () {
    $scope.groups = [{
    title: "Dynamic Group Header - 4",
    content: "Dynamic Group Body - 4"
}, {
    title: "Dynamic Group Header - 5",
    content: "Dynamic Group Body - 5"
}];
};
}
function f()
{document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<button id='btn2' ng-click='addItem()'>add d item</button>";}
```

Comment: The point of Angular is to let you write declarative and dynamic HTML. So you shouldn't imperatively generate it from your JavaScript. While you may not be using JQuery this answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: That is bad practice, what are you trying to do exactly? I see you are using the accordion demo for angular ui

Comment: i want to generate theses tabs from web api json data by updating $scope.groups variable

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS doesn't normally parse HTML you add to the page at runtime using the DOM, so it doesn't automatically catch angular directive uses there.  However, you can do an explicit call after you modify the page to have it reparse. Take a look at: [AngularJS + JQuery : How to get dynamic content working in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771513/angularjs-jquery-how-to-get-dynamic-content-working-in-angularjs)

Comment: Many people are going to point out that if your page is not very complex, you should not need to modify the DOM directly when you are using AngularJS. =) Consider using ng-if and ng-repeat. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

Consider this,

Don't dynamically generate the element you want angular to parse - instead create it in your HTML. Use ng-show or ng-hide to dynamically show or hide the section.

This is a technique even used in the course that solves a similar problem at [Code School](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js).