# AJAXing HTML from other page only after other page fully rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, angularjs

I have a quick question to ask. Right now I have:

`$('#thisPageDiv').load(url + ' #otherPageDiv');`

The AJAX request fires and `#otherPageDiv` is successfully rendered in `#thisPageDiv`. However, because my other page uses AngularJS, the retrieved result is barebones and practically useless. Is there any way I can ensure that the retrieved data is fully rendered? I wouldn't mind if it's hacky (such as rendering the whole page in the beginning, and then only retrieving the important portion after the full load).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call $compile so angular does his job first.
Checkout: [AngularJS + JQuery : How to get dynamic content working in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771513/angularjs-jquery-how-to-get-dynamic-content-working-in-angularjs)

The a look in the comments too ... Maybe angularjs can do the whole job for you without the jquery ajax call.