# get content out of angular expression with jquery fails

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently updating parts of my asp.net mvc 5 webapp to angularjs 1.5.

As not everything is angular js, some parts are done with jQuery.

Before angularjs I had 
`<h2>@Model.title</h2>` which become `<h2>Document XYZ</h2>`
After moving to angular I'm having a 
`<h2>{{ document.title }}</h2>`

I'm trying to get the Document Title out of it and use it somewhere else with jQuery selector
`$('#documentId').find("h2").text()`

Unfortunately, since changing to angular all I get is the expression `{{ document.title }}`, but not the content which is rendered sucessfully.

Any ideas?

Comment: put the angularjs variable in a service and use it where you want. Do not mix jquery and angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call $compile on the HTML string before inserting it into the DOM so that angular gets a chance to perform the binding.

In your fiddle, it would look something like this.

```
$("#dynamicContent").html(
  $compile(
    "<h2>{{ document.title }}</h2>"
  )(scope)
);
```

For more reference please check this link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771513/angularjs-jquery-how-to-get-dynamic-content-working-in-angularjs)