# Why html element not working if I attach it using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I work on my angularjs project.

I try to append html-string to some div using JQuery like that:

```
 var html = '<a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sitesDamages.sitesList" style="padding: 11px 09px;" title="events"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i></a>'     
 $("#inspectorArea").append(html);
```

After I append the html-string the icon appears on the appended div but , when I click on the icon it's not work(when I navigate mouse on anchor mouse not converted to the pointer and when I click on the icon in the anchor I don't get any reaction.)

While if I put html element direct on the template it works fine.

Any idea why html-string not working if I append it as string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS + JQuery : How to get dynamic content working in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771513/angularjs-jquery-how-to-get-dynamic-content-working-in-angularjs)