# How do I bind ng-model attribute to jQuery element which is generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller

The below code generates the form dynamically. - This is written in Angular js 1.4

```
    var $label = $('<label display="inline-block" width=25px>').text(jsonObj.ATTRIBUTES[key].ATTRIBUTE_NAME+' :  ');
    var $input = $('<input type="text">').attr({id: jsonObj.ATTRIBUTES[key].ATTRIBUTE_NAME+'Id', name: jsonObj.ATTRIBUTES[key].ATTRIBUTE_NAME, 'ng-model':'entity.'+jsonObj.ATTRIBUTES[key].ATTRIBUTE_NAME});
    $input.appendTo($label);
    $('#dynamicContent').append($label).append('<br/>');
```

Next this 'dynamicContent' id is there in the JSP as below

```
start form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()"
div id='dynamicContent'
end form
```

Now, how do I make sure the form submits, and I will be able to access 'entity' in the controller?

PS: New to Angular and jQuery
Please suggest how do I go ahead in case I just use Angular.

Comment: If you are new to both, get rid of using jQuery if you are building an angular app. What you are currently doing is already imporper

Comment: @charlietfl Okay, but then how do I proceed using angular? any leads?

Comment: You need to include the label (and the input) inside #dynamicContent and not generate the label using jQuery. If you have some logic which determines whether the form will be visible, then use ng-show

Comment: @BharatGupta But the label and the input are dynamic and I get those from a Webservice. I really cannot hard code the label inside #dynamicContent as you have suggested :( any other means?

Comment: You know the html structure and the content is dynamic. That is normal and what angular is good at. I strongly suggest you go through some thorough angular tutorials

Answer (score 0):

You need to `$compile` your html fragment against the controller's scope and then append it the `#dynamicContent`. For this, you would need to inject `$compile` in your controller.

Sample code:

```
var htmlContent = "<prepare-your-html-using-jquery>";
$("#dynamicContent").append(
  $compile(htmlContent)(scope);
);
```

Reference: [angularjs-jquery-how-to-get-dynamic-content-working-in-angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771513/angularjs-jquery-how-to-get-dynamic-content-working-in-angularjs)

Comment: this snippet works, but then how do I go about my requirement? both the label and the corresponding input field are dynamic and i'll have to form only using jQuery I suppose.

Comment: @devk you can always prepare the string beforehand using jQuery and then pass that string to `$compile`

Comment: @devk I have updated the answer so that you can visualize.

Comment: Thanks, I am now able to form a String, the problem is when I submit the form, I am unable to get the value which is there in the ng-model attribute. Any ideas?

Comment: @devk Can you create a fiddle so that I can help you debug it?